# How to pass the checkbox value on controller in angularjs using icheck plugin

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, icheck

Hi I am new in `Angular js`.

I am using the `Icheck` plugin for `checkbox` design in front end.In that I'm unable to get `checkbox` value from front end.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="createLeaveTypeForm.allow_encashment" name="allow_encashment" class="flat" >
<span style="margin-left: 5px;">Allow Encashment</span> </label>
```

If I get the value using `$scope.createLeaveTypeForm.allow_encashment` it shows undifinded.Anyone guide me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rr2LLqoe/19/)

Comment: Have you initialized the $scope.createLeaveTypeForm.allow_encashment in the controller ?

Comment: @geo I have already initialized the $scope.createLeaveTypeForm.allow_encashment in the controller its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to init checkbox scope value, initialize scope something like below for default unchecked;

```
$scope.createLeaveTypeForm.allow_encashment = false;
```

And defualt checked

```
$scope.createLeaveTypeForm.allow_encashment = true;
```

Comment: ok, if possible can you make fiddle for this. So, that we can reproduce the issue :)

Comment: @mohan I think you forgot to include angularjs libs in fiddle or I m missing something?